# UserInfo endpoint not in well known url (https://login.live.com/.well-known/openid-configuration)

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

I am implementing authentication using openid connect. I have successfully implemented the openid - connect in my website. I am using well know url (https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration) to get the endpoint detail so method should be generic for all the sources (google, microsoft etc). But in microsoft well known url https://login.live.com/.well-known/openid-configuration I did not find userinfo endpoint so that I can get the user information. I need the user's firstname and email. Will I get this info using id_token??

Please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried this guide https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659736.aspx ?